# Return column of joined rows as array instead of object

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm having a problem which is a little difficult for me to explain.

I have two database tables:

| ID | FRUIT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |

| FRUIT_ID | COLOR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Red |
| 1 | Green |
| 2 | Orange |

The idea behind this: A Fruit can have multiple colors.
To get all the colors from all the fruits I have to join them:

SELECT a.*, b.color
FROM Fruit a, FruitColor b
WHERE a.id = b.fruit_id

| ID | FRUIT | COLOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Red |
| 1 | Apple | Green |
| 2 | Orange | Orange |

The JSON would look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "FRUIT": "Apple",
    "COLOR": "Red"
  },
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "FRUIT": "Apple",
    "COLOR": "GREEN"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "FRUIT": "Orange",
    "COLOR": "Orange"
  }
]
```

**And here comes the problem**
I actually don't want to return an object for every extra color, I need them in an array like this:

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "FRUIT": "Apple",
    "COLOR": [
      "Red",
      "Green"
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "FRUIT": "Orange",
    "COLOR": "Orange"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?
It doesn't matter if I have to change the DB structure or the query, any solution to this would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`JSON_ARRAYAGG`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) function twice in order to encapsulate the colors firstly, and objects with the second apply such as

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(js) AS Result
  FROM (SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id',
                           f.id,
                           'fruit',
                           f.fruit,
                           'state',
                           JSON_ARRAYAGG(fc.color)) AS js
          FROM Fruit AS f
          JOIN FruitColor AS fc
            ON f.id = fc.fruit_id
         GROUP BY f.id, f.fruit) j
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=926c634743393765bd3853044dff5cb3)</kbd>

Comment: you're welcome @TE4L , good luck!